# Best way to manage multiple apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, amazon-web-services, architecture, web-deployment

I am working on an application with different rails apps.
We are moving fast and pushing code often to each of them ... and each stack depends on the other (we have internal APIs)

I can't find any article with best practices in this case.

Should I have all the apps in the same git repo and each stack would be a submodule?
When I deploy should I always deploy all the stacks together?

Anyway it sounds like a pretty common problem but I can't find any good documentation about it.

Comment: are you about that one http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29

Comment: Sorry for the confusion ... by stacks I meant apps, just edited to make it more readable

Comment: @Elie these apps are interrelated or different?

Comment: @Mandeep The apps are interrelated, one is an API that the other one uses

Comment: @Elie if they are interrelated then i don't think there is any problem is using same repo just make sure everyone push code is small chunks and yeah it'll be better if you setup a staging server and at the end of day push all of your work first on staging and if everything seems to be working fine then only push code on the production server

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use `git` to push your application to your server, much [how `Heroku` does it](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git)

We've achieved this functionality on our own stack at Rackspace, whereby we had to do several important things to gte it working.

---

**Deploy**

As a rule of thumb:

> The deployment of applications is different than the updating of code.
>   Whilst I don't know the technical terminology, I *do* know that if
>   you're pushing code to a single app, that will be completely different
>   to "deploying" multiple apps.

To this end, I recommend treating the two processes separate to each other. IE you should only push code to specific repositories, and deploy the "application" as you see fit.

As you've not detailed any specifics of your stack, let me give you my interpretation, based on our work with our own RackSpace stack.

---

**Git**

The backbone of what you're looking for is `git` - which will give you the ability to perform ["single click deploy"](http://www.sitepoint.com/one-click-app-deployment-server-side-git-hooks/):

[image]

The trick is to create a `bare` repository on your server (much the same way as Github & Heroku do), and then gives you the ability to "push" your code to these hooks. To do this, you'll  need to do several things (namely set up a `git` repo, route it on your server, and then create any `post-receive hooks` to manage deployment):

--

**Bare Repo**

The first step is to set up a `bare repo`, which can be done very simply

If you SSH into your EC2 instance, just run the following command:

```
$ git init --bare /git/your_app.git
```

This will give you a repository which you can then "push" your code to. The difference between this, and a working repository, is that the bare one will not have any files - just references & other information. The trick is to [use a `hook`](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) to create a working directory, which you can then use to run your application from.

The bare repo will allow you to push the code you need, and essentially giving you the functionality that Github & others possess -- the ability to "send" your code to the server succinctly.

--

**Host**

Secondly, you then need to be able to "route" any requests to this git repo, and presumably, other git repos you have too. To do this, you'll need to capture any requests with your webserver. Here's how to do it with Nginx:

```
#/etc/nginx/sites-available/git
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name your_domain.com;
        root /git;

        auth_basic  "RESTRICTED ACCESS";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

        location ~ ^.*\.git/(HEAD|info/refs|objects/info/.*|git-(upload|receive$
                root /gitk;

                client_max_body_size                    100M;

                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME           /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend
                fastcgi_param REMOTE_USER               $remote_user;
                fastcgi_param GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL       "";
                fastcgi_param GIT_PROJECT_ROOT          /git;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO                 $uri;
                fastcgi_pass                            unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

You'll want to [use htpasswd to create an authentication file](http://weavervsworld.com/docs/other/passprotect.html) (haven't created authorization for this yet), which then should allow you to process the following locally:

```
> git remote add production http://your_domain.com/your_repo.git
> git add .
> git commit -a -m "Production"
> git push production master
```

This will ask you to authenticate, to which you'll have to use the details you provided in the `auth` file.

--

**Hook**

Finally, you'll then be able to use the many [git hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) to create a "deploy" mechanism. Typically, you'd use [`post-receive`](https://gist.github.com/yortz/1047083):

```
#git/your_app.git/hooks
cd /app/your_app
git --work-tree=${APP_PATH} --git-dir=${GIT_DIR} checkout -f
bundle install
touch tmp/restart.txt
```

This, obviously, is very basic. You can make it as elaborate as you like, even combining other repos if you wish!

Hope this gives you some ideas!